# I'm pretty new to laravel and I'm doing user sign up and login but I'm getting an error

Tags: php, laravel

The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
I'm pretty new to laravel and I'm doing user sign up and login but I'm  getting an error

This is the controller which is giving an error

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\facade;
use Request;
use DB;

class hotsmoke extends Controller
{
    function login() {

        return view('hot_smoke_login');

    }

    function signup() {

        return view('sign-Up');

    }

    function login2() {

        return view('dashboard');

    }

    function store() {

        $uname= Request::input('name');

        $uemail = Request::input('email');

        $unumber= Request::input('number');

        $uaddress= Request::input('address');

        $upass= Request::input('password');




        DB::unprepared("insert into customers (name, email,number,address,password) values ('$uname','$uemail','$unumber','$uaddress','$upass')");
         return redirect('/hot_smoke_login');

    }
    function match2() {

        $uemail = Request::input('email');

        $upass = Request::input('password');



        $loginData = DB::select('select password from users where email = ?', [$uemail]);

     

        if (count($loginData) > 0){

           

            foreach ($loginData as $tablepass) {



                if (($tablepass->password) == $upass){

                    return view('dashboard');

                }

                else{

                    $error='Password does not match';

                    return view('hot_smoke_login')->with('error',$error);

                }

            }

        }

    }


}
```

my blade view which is not running as mentioned

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Hotsmoke</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 p-0" style=" height: 100vh; overflow: hidden;">
        <img src="images/hero-img.jpg" alt="" width="100%">
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 p-5">
        <a href="javascript: history.go(-1)"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left backBtn"></i></a>
        <div class="align-items-center justify-content-center d-flex flex-column">
          <h3 class="text-white">Login to <strong style="color: #ce913a;">HotSmoke</strong></h3>
          <p class="mb-4 secondary-color">We know the cuisines and your taste better than anyone!</p>
          <form method="post" id="login">
            <div class="form-group first d-flex flex-column">
              <label class="primary-color" for="username">Email</label>
              <input type="text" class="email" id="username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group last mb-3 d-flex flex-column">
              <label class="primary-color" for="password">Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="email" id="password">
            </div>

            <div class="d-flex mb-1 align-items-center">
              <label class="control control--checkbox mb-0"><span class="caption">Remember me</span>
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
                <div class="control__indicator"></div>
              </label>
              <span class="ml-auto"><a href="forget-password.html" class="forgot-pass" style="color: #e0ae66">Forgot
                  Password</a></span>
            </div>
            <a href="sign-Up.html" class="secondary-color">Do not have an Account?</a>
            <small class="text-danger " id="error" style="display: none;"></small>
            <br><br>
            <button class="email-button">Log In</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5e8b9def84.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/login.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and my routes are

```
Route::get('sign-Up', [hotsmoke::class, 'signup']);
Route::post('sign-Up', [hotsmoke::class, 'store']);
Route::get('hot_smoke_login', [hotsmoke::class, 'login']);
Route::get('hot_smoke_login', [hotsmoke::class, 'match2']);
```

please guide me

Comment: What's the route generating the error?

Comment: Route::post('sign-Up', [hotsmoke::class, 'store']);

Comment: Looks like the form has no action attribute. Add one and specify the route.

Comment: Why not use the [native Laravel auth system](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication)? Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and you're storing plain text passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will work. In each an every input field add the name attribute and mention the name you want to call it.

For example `<input type="text" class="email" name="username">` , do this to every input and after the form tag use **@csrf** token like this and the route name should be the action,

```
<form action="/sign-Up" method="post" id="login">
@csrf
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the first thing you need to do is add an 'action' attribute to your form element which points to the endpoint you want to submit the form to
so in this case it will look like

```
action="{{ url('/sign-Up') }}"
```